# How should I approach a Sharepoint 2010 development project coming from WebForms and MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a good amount of knowledge in the ASP.NET Webforms and MVC worlds.  Shortly I will be tasked with implementing custom web applications with Sharepoint.  I have great flexibility with this project (i.e - I can use custom web apps outside of Sharepoint if that's possible) but like most projects the most limiting factor I have to deal with is time.

Here are some questions that come to mind:

1. Can I easily integrate a custom MVC project into Sharepoint 2010?  What are the pros and cons if I can?
2. Same as #1 only with Webforms.
3. If #1 and #2 are not viable solutions, can I easily create custom web applications within the Sharepoint world?  What will the learning curve be with my background?
4. I understand developers can now use Windows 7 to deliver Sharepoint 2010 solutions.  It looks like I can use a trial of Microsoft Sharepoint Foundations 2010.  If that's correct, are there any development differences or gotchas I need to be aware of before digging into the Foundation version?  I don't want to get up to speed on Foundation and then find out that the Server edition (the version that will be deployed) is vastly different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is based on webforms - it is relatively easy to add custom user controls and web parts, though if you want to use SharePoint data in a completely custom web app, especially mvc you will probably need to host it seperately - you can access everything you need through the SharePoint API, but it makes the deployment a lot more complicated.

The workarounds to get webforms mvc running in the SharePoint web app tend to involve stuff that would never get past corporate infrastructure people, but I've been getting good results with precompiled razor views set up based on http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ - my version that produces code which can be included in a SharePoint project is at https://github.com/tqc/RazorEngine

In the 2007 version there were significant architectural differences between WSS and MOSS. With 2010 there aren't as many differences, so you should be ok, but it would still be better to develop on the same version you are deploying to - download a trial of Standard or one of the demo VMs - If you do a lot of .net development, chances are you already have an appropriate dev license.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Are you connecting your MVC site to SharePoint or are you building something "MVC" on top of the SharePoint server?

In any case, there is an MVC SharePoint project on Codeplex here http://sharepointmvc.codeplex.com/

Here is an article on the subject http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2009/03/17/asp-net-mvc-and-sharepoint.aspx

I havent touched it, and it seems a bit abandoned to me, but it might get you along.

Check out it outlines one method of running [MVC](http://aspalliance.com/1944_Using_ASPNET_MVC_2_with_Sharepoint_Publishing) with SharePoint

Generally, SharePoint will simplify many user-oriented requirements you may have - such as authentication, permissions control and personalised areas (with MySites).

If you go with SharePoint, you almost have to build your product for SharePoint Foundation so that you can keep your customers' total costs low (SharePoint CALs, SQL Server, hardware, etc). You'll want to build friendly user interfaces for managing permission, allowing your users to create their own pages, and other provisioning tasks -- or provide rock-solid documentation on how to do it out of the box with SharePoint. With SharePoint, you should use features and Web Parts to deploy your code either way , whether SaaS or on-premise. That will make it easier to deploy and upgrade.